# Flutter cannot find build tools

Tags: android, flutter, android-build, flutter-android, android-buildconfig

Flutter cannot find any build tools for any version given to it.
I've been through this for 3 weeks and search anywhere still not find any solution.

Here is the error message
[image]

Here is my zshrc
[image]

Here is flutter doctor results
[image]

I have tried for various build tools versions but it keep giving this error message

Comment: delete the build folder then run it

Comment: Please paste the errors in the text editor, and any other problem related in as text.